# UITextField display output of ReverseGeoCoder From Location Class

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, core-location

I have ViewController with a search interface with a number of UITextFields.

One of the Fields is a location field, where there is an option to use the current location.

When the user clicks the get current location button, which is next to the UITextField, this triggers a ReverseGeoCoding method in a separate class  I have set up to handle the location methods.

Is it possible for the text returned from the placeholder to then be populated into my SearchViewControllers text Field.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) or [notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to share datas between your different controllers.

Comment: Great thanks, I have used delegation and it works well, for what I want to achieve.